# Performing a function's criterion within another

Tags: r, function

This is fairly difficult for me to explain, however, I wish to use a function that's within a function, that can be used towards the variables.

For example, given that the function looks similar to this:

```
test <- function(a, b, c){
a <- ...
b <- ...
c <- ...
}

#used likeso:

test(a = ..., b = ..., c = ...)
```

Is it possible to use it likeso:

```
test(a = ..., c(b = ...))
```

And what's an example of how this function would look like? I'm looking for a function like this because I'm trying to index a function within a function, that can be used like the second function above.

I know that this can be achieved with two separate function, though, I'm asking as to whether its possible with one function, whilst having another function indexed within it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `do.call` like this:

```
test <- function(a, b, c) a + b + c
do.call("test", list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)) 
## [1] 6
```